# Pycharm - Why some of my python code marked in red?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am writing (what I believe to be) valid code, yet Pycharm marks some of my code
in red. The code works fine and hovering over the red marked code doesnt show any suggestions or issues. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: That's the colour kwargs are being highlighted in. It does not indicate an error.

Comment: are you sure it's red? looks more like dark orange to me, indicating is  a named parameter.

Comment: Is there any way to remove this particular colorization? It doesn't go hand in hand with my undiagnosed ocd.

Comment: Actual errors are highlighted differently, usually with a red squiggly underline. I think it'd be best if you got used to the colour scheme. You can of course customise it in the settings…

Comment: I'm new to Python but have been using JetBrains IDEs for over a decade with other languages. This is the first time I've ever seen them pick a color that's red (or redish) for such syntax. It's ridiculous IMO. I spent a while trying to debug the issue only to come across this thread where it's allegedly normal. -1 JetBrains.